# Clean up the yum cache after upgrading Fedora 13 to 14

Tags: fedora, cache, yum

I updated from Fedora 11 to Fedora 13, and then to Fedora 14. My disk space has been decreasing and I've noticed that `/var/cache/yum/i386/13/updates` occupies 800M

I've run the following:

```
yum clean all  
yum clean packages --enablerepo="*"
```

but disk usage is always the same.

Surely there is something I'm doing wrong.
Anyone out there have a hint?

Answer (score 2):

The F13 repo information is no longer available to yum.

```
\rm -r /var/cache/yum/i386/13
```